# Download File from File-Server via Script

Tags: java, php, web-services, download, cloud

I have e.g. three file-servers and want to add a "Transparency-Layer" for filedownloads (one single script which is executed, fetches the file and sends it directly to the user).

Users should only use one link to access a file e.g.:

```
www.mysite.com/download/<UUID_WITH_correctFileServer>
```

The questions I am asking now are:

- Is it possible to offer the users a single access-url (e.g. above) with good performance?
- I think that using just one java-servlet or php-script is not as performant as having one script on each fileserver -> my speculation: file is sent from fileserver to central script and from there to the user. correct?
- How do other cloud-storage-providers have solved this issue?

Comment: It depends on how you write your code. If you read the file and send it to your clients from your server or if you redirect your clients to the server where the file is.

Comment: Hi, i will do some security checks and then i want to send the file to the user (Redirect will be ok i think). Is there a sample code? Is this done by setting the header?

Comment: I think  `header("Location: `ftp ://username:password@somedomain.com/somefile.ext");`
should do it (assuimng you would need an username and password).
I wanted to type ftp://

Comment: Great, so just setting this header will directly send the file to the user (not over the script location too) right?

Comment: Would you prefer a java servelt or pho for that?

Comment: I prefer PHP only because I know it a little. 
If the user must stay on the page (your page), I am not sure but you might need some JS/Ajax thing to trigger the donwload from the client side.

Comment: If you could put your comment into an answer, I could give you a vote and close this question. if you could prepare the header to be ready-to-use I would be very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy... will try...  only the first file in the examples will actually work ok? (real file in a real server).

If you don't care about navigating away you could do something like:

**test.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['fname']) and $_GET['fname']){
    // do something with filename to decide from where to donwload
    if($_GET['fname']=="DWSM_Domain.png") header("Location: ftp://anonymous:test@mailinator.com@ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/pub/CFWI_HAT/DWSM_Domain.png");  
    if($_GET['fname']=="file1") header("Location: ftp://someuser:somepassword@ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/somepath/file1");
    if($_GET['fname']=="file2") header("Location: ftp://someuser:somepassword@ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/somepath/file2");
    exit;
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="/test.php?fname=DWSM_Domain.png">DWSM_Domain.png</a></p>
    <p><a href="/test.php?fname=file1">file1</a></p>
    <p><a href="/test.php?fname=file2">file2</a></p>
</body>
```

If you do want the user to open another window you will need two php files.

**test1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><label onclick="get_file('DWSM_Domain.png')">DWSM_Domain.png</label></p>
    <p><label  onclick="get_file('file1')">file1</label></p>
    <p><label  onclick="get_file('file2')">file2</label></p>
    <script>
        function get_file(thisfile) {
            if(thisfile){
                var content;
                var page = "/test2.php?fname="; 
                var address = page.concat(thisfile);
                $.get(address, function (data) {
                    content = data;
                    var newWindow = window.open("","_blank");
                    newWindow.location.href = content;
                });
            } 
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['fname']) and $_GET['fname']){
        // do something with filename to decide from where to donwload
        if($_GET['fname']=="DWSM_Domain.png") $targetfile ="ftp://anonymous:test@mailinator.com@ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/pub/CFWI_HAT/DWSM_Domain.png";   
        if($_GET['fname']=="file1") $targetfile ="ftp://someuser:somepassword@ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/somepath/file1";
        if($_GET['fname']=="file2") $targetfile ="ftp://someuser:somepassword@ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/somepath/file2";

        echo $targetfile;
    }
?>
```

You certainly will need to tame it to get your exact behaviour but I hope is a good start.
Fair winds

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, but it depends on the performance of the server you're hosting the script on, and on the users' internet connection

Comment: The servers are not in the same network, so the user should be redirected to the original file after some security checks